# Trouble connecting Thunderbolt duo to network via ethernet/thunderbolt connector

Tags: network

I have a thunderbolt duo which is used with my Macbook Pro, but I want to use it also with my 2009 iMac. I've tried to connect using the thunderbolt/ethernet adapter, first into my gigabit switch and then straight into the iMac but it doesn't pick up?!

Can anyone help with this, so I can use the thunderbolt duo with my iMac until it's time to get a new iMac.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **You can't**

The 2009 iMac is pre-Thunderbolt, and Thunderbolt is not backwards compatible as far as I am aware.

From what I can see the DUO only has a Thuderbolt port, so you will be out of luck unless you can find a Thunderbolt to USB converter. I am not sure if those exist to be honest.

The only option I can suggest is to enable sharing between your iMac and your MacBook Pro and share the DUO of the MacBook Pro instead.